# Typescript Class.prototype.MyFunction makes errors but working

Tags: angularjs

I can't explain why I get an error **but code works**. Is that compiler bug? (I use Visual Studio Code with Angular 2)

```
class A
{
    fun(a: number)
    {
        return a+2;
    }
}


A.prototype.F = function() { return "F here!"+this.fun(1); } // This makes error: The property 'F' does not exist on value of type 'A'



var a: A = new A();

console.log(a.F());
```

And bonus: This is not working at all! (no access to this.fun())

```
A.prototype.F2 = () => { return "F2 here!"+this.fun(1); } // ()=>{} is not working! cause _this is not defined!
...  
console.log(a.F2());
```

**Edit #1**

As @seangwright said I need to use [Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) but...

As far as it's working with simple example with my `A` class I can't make it work with Angular's ComponentFixture. This should solve my problem if I do this like in Typescript example:

```
declare module '@angular/core/testing' // I was trying without this line and with 'global' instead of '@angular/core/testing' but nothing helps
{
    interface ComponentFixture<T>
    {
        TestOf(cssSelector: string): string;
    }
}
```

But I still get an error:

> 'ComponentFixture' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value
>   here.'

at this point:

```
ComponentFixture.prototype.TextOf = function(cssSelector: string): string 
{   
 ...
}
```

There is even more errors, for example when I try to use it:

```
let fixture: ComponentFixture<EditableValueComponent>;
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditableValueComponent);
```

I got:

> 'ComponentFixture' is not assignable to type
>   'ComponentFixture'. Two different types with
>   this name exist, but they are unrelated.   Property 'TestOf' is
>   missing in type 'ComponentFixture'

So again: Code works but has many compilation errors. Or maybe I'm missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling you are a C# developer based on how you format your code.

### Part 1

In Typescript once you declare your class, the type system expects it to have the properties (shape) you define and that's it.

The more of the type system you want to use, the less dynamic your objects will/can be.

That said, the reason your code runs (transpiles) correctly is because this is an error in the context of Typescript's structural type system, not Javascript's dynamic type system. So Typescript will tell you `A` doesn't have a property `F` at compile time, but Javascript doesn't care that it's added at runtime.

One solution is to [merge the class with an interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

```
class A {
    fun(a: number) {
        return a + 2;
    }
}

interface A {
    F(): string;
}

A.prototype.F = function () { return "F here!" + this.fun(1); }

var a: A = new A();

console.log(a.F());
```

Another would be to temporarily abandon the type system

```
class A {
    fun(a: number) {
        return a + 2;
    }
}

(A.prototype as any).F = function () { return "F here!" + this.fun(1); }

var a: A = new A();

console.log((a as any).F());
```

But that becomes verbose and prone to errors and loses the benefits that a type system brings.

You mention you are using Typescript with Angular 2. You could write in ES2015 if you wanted a more dynamic syntax. But then you will lose some of the benefits that Angular 2 gets from using Typescript (better tooling, smaller deployments).

### Part 2

The reason your second example doesn't work at all has nothing to do with Typescript and everything to do with [Scope (or execution context)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) in Javascript, specifically [ES2015 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

> An arrow function does not create its own this context, so this has its original meaning from the enclosing context.

Unlike in your first example you are not using the traditional `function` declaration syntax and instead are using the `() => {}` arrow function syntax. With your first example

`A.prototype.F = function() { return "F here!"+this.fun(1); }`

`this` refers to whatever context `F()` is going to be executing in. Since you define it on the prototype of `A` it is going to be executing in the context of `A`. `A` has a `.fun()` method so `this.fun()` is going to be the same one defined in your class above.

With your second example, `F2` is not going to be executing in the context of `A` despite being defined as a method of its prototype. The arrow function syntax is instead going to allow `F2` to run in the context of the `enclosing context` which is the global `window` object unless you are running in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) in which case

> in browsers it's no longer possible to reference the window object through this inside a strict mode function.

So `this` will be `undefined` and calling `fun()` on `undefined` is going to throw an error.

Try adding a `console.log(this)` to your `F2` function.

```
A.prototype.F2 = () => { console.log(this); return "F2 here!"+this.fun(1); }
```

When you run the transpiled Javascript you will probably see `Window` logged out to the console, and then probably an error like `Uncaught TypeError: _this.fun is not a function`

Use the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) to write some Typescript, see what the tooling tells you, what transpiled Javascript is created and then run it to see if your Javascript is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for an answer but I still can't make it work :( And yes, I love C# syntax :)

Comment: @tBlabs what can't you make work, exactly? Also, I should note that some of what the Typescript compiler and editor tooling tells you is possible is going to depend on which editor and which version of Typescript you are using.